# detect for future element exist and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a plugin where it will create new element into my DOM, but unfortunately it don't have callback after the plugin initialized. So I'm thinking of catching the new created DOM and execute certain function. What is the best way to listen to the future coming element?

I've tried 2 methods

1. use setTimeout
   The flaw of this method is that it is very risky to assume every user will able to initiated the plugin with the same load time.
2. use livequery plugin (https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)
   This work but bad for performances. It still run after I catched the new coming element.

Comment: Do you want to simply attach handler functions to events on DOM elements that have not yet been created such as do something on click or similar?

Comment: @JohnIdol that can be done using on(), but in my case I have to do something else..

Comment: So you want to detect when the new element is appended to the DOM, correct?

Comment: @JohnIdol yes. exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that the plugin you are using does not have something like a callback, but if you really want to check if an element is in the DOM, you could select that element (e.g. by id/class) and check if it is already existing:

```
function checkIfThere() { 
  if ($('.yourEl').length > 0) console.log("There it is!");
  else setTimeout(checkIfThere, 100); // recall the function until it is in the DOM
};
```

with this way you assign your timeout to recall the function every time the element is not loaded, until it is.